# How to define jaxws-endpoint with Spring annotations?

Tags: java, spring, web-services, soap, wsdl

Is it possible to rewrite the following xml soap webservice config to annotation based spring config?

```
  <jaxws:endpoint xmlns:tns="http://ws.sample.org/" id="helloservice"
        implementor="org.sample.ws.HelloServiceImpl" wsdlLocation="wsdl/helloserviceimpl.wsdl"
        endpointName="tns:HelloServiceImplPort" serviceName="tns:HelloServiceImplService"
        address="/HelloServiceImplPort" />
```

The following approach is not detected:

```
@Service
@Webservice(serviceName="helloservice", wsdlLocation="wsdl/helloserviceimpl.wsdl", targetNamespace = "http://ws.sample.org/")
public class HelloServiceImpl {
    @WebMethod
    public String getVersion() {
        return "1.0";
    }
}
```